# Updating columns in Database Access c#

Tags: c#

I have 2 tables in database, tblIPAddress and tblDepartment.

On click of update button, I managed to update everything except for for 1 column(DepartmentID) because of the way I add items on the combobox(cmbDepartment).

DepartmentID column is numbers only. I am identifying each department by ID Number.

Example: 1=IT, 2=Accounts etc.

My question is how to update the column (DepartmentID) with numbers equal to the selected department in combobox?

Code I use to add items on combobox (cmbDepartment)

```
            string query = "select ID, Department from tblDepartment";
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, myConn);

            DataSet dsdpt = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(dsdpt, "tblDepartment");
            cmbDepartment.DataSource = dsdpt.Tables["tblDepartment"];
            cmbDepartment.ValueMember = "ID";
            cmbDepartment.DisplayMember = "Department";
```

Code I use to update table(tblIPAddress)

```
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = myConn;
            string query = "";
            query = "update tblIPAddress set E_Name=@E_Name, DepartmentID=@DepartmentID , E_Username=@E_Username, E_Password=@E_Password, E_Extension=@E_Extension, E_MobileNo=@E_MobileNo, Remarks=@Remarks, Modified_by=@Modified_by, Modified_on=@Modified_on where IP_Address=@IP_Address";

            command.CommandText = query;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@E_Name", this.txtname.Text);              
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@E_Username", this.txtusern.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@E_Password", this.txtpwd.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@E_Extension", this.txtext.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@E_MobileNo", this.txtmobile.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", this.txtrmk.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Modified_by", Loginfrm.userlogged);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Modified_on", DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IP_Address", this.txtip.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentID", this.cmbDepartment.Text);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("IP Details Updated");
```

Comment: The value (ID) of the selected item in the combobox is available through the property SelectedValue (cast to integer)

Comment: This actually works, instead of .text just make it .SelectedValue.

Comment: Yes but the answer from Soner Gonul is more complete and suggest you best practices. Please try to follow his advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`OleDbCommand.Parameters` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx)

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
> parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
> `OleDbCommand` when `CommandType` is set to Text. In this case, the
> question mark `(?)` placeholder must be used. For example:
>
> `SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?`
>
> Therefore, the order in which `OleDbParameter` objects are added to the
> `OleDbParameterCollection` must directly correspond to the position of
> the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

Since you didn't provide your parameter values with the same order in your command, this generate a problem. Change your parameter values with the same order that you defined in your command.

Also as Steve mentioned, you might need to add `@DepartmentID` value as `(int)cmbDepartment.SelectedValue` instead of `Text` property.

A few things more;

- Do not store your `DateTime` values as a string. It is a bad habit. Change your `Modified_on` column some datetime type and pass your `DateTime.Today` value directly. Read: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)
- Don't use `AddWithValue` as much as you can. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overloads to specify your parameter type and it's size.
- Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection, command and adapter automatically as well.
- Do **not** store your passwords as a plain text. Read: [Best way to store password in database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1054022/447156)

Comment: Thank you for the tips. It will be very helpful since I'm just a newbie. I will bear it in mind.